# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error, angular material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to use dialogs of angular material, I added the `ngMaterial` dependency to my module, and had a reference to the angular material in my layout page, and added the `$mdDialog` to the controller, 
here's is my module:

```
var tapp = angular.module('tApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial']);
```

and controller:

```
tapp.controller('tCtrlr', function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog) {//code})
```

this is all the libraries references

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-material/angular-material-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ngApp/_TApp.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ngApp/_TController.js"></script>

</head>
```

and still having this error

> $injector:modulerr Module Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the necessary references needed for the angular material,

add the following ,

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I'm only missing the angular-aria?

Comment: I have angular-animate

Comment: yea then fine, did you try